# Error when install postgresql in linux mint sarah

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu, installation

I want to install postgresql in my computer Linux mint sarah, and I finish procedure installation but when I type psql in my cmd postgres error, like this :

Error when install PostgreSQL

> psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
>       Is the server running locally and accepting
>       connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

how I fixed that  ??
thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error states that the psql utility can't find the socket to connect to your database server.

Either you don't have the database service running in the background, or the socket is located elsewhere, or perhaps the pg_hba.conf needs to be fixed.

**Step 1: Verify that the database is running**

The command may vary depending on your operating system. But on most *ix systems the following would work, it will search for postgres among all running processes

```
ps -ef | grep postgres
```

On my system, mac osx, this spits out

```
501   408     1   0  2Jul15 ??         0:21.63 /usr/local/opt/postgresql/bin/postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres -r /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log
```

The last column shows the command used to start the server, and the options.

You can look at all the options available to start the postgres server using the following.

```
man postgres
```

From there, you'd see that the options -D and -r are respectively the datadir & the logfilename.
**Step 2: If the postgres service is running**

Use find to search for the location of the socket, which should be somewhere in the /tmp

```
sudo find /tmp/ -name .s.PGSQL.5432
```

If postgres is running and accepting socket connections, the above should tell you the location of the socket. On my machine, it turned out to be:

```
/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

Then, try connecting via psql using this file's location explicitly, eg.

```
psql -h /tmp/ dbname
```

**Step 3: If the service is running but you don't see a socket**

If you can't find the socket, but see that the service is running, Verify that the `pg_hba.conf` file allows local sockets.

Browse to the datadir and you should find the pg_hba.conf file.

By default, near the bottom of the file you should see the following lines:

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local       all       all       trust
```

If you don't see it, you can modify the file, and restart the postgres service.